# Storing up to 32 int into an array MIPS

Tags: mips, mips64, smips

I am trying to store numbers of type int into an Array in MIPS this is what I have so far, but obviously since I do not have enough registers to do it this way it is not efficient. In the ends I am pretty much sorting the array. Any help?

```
.data   
array:  .space  32              #saves space for array with undefined values
comma:  .asciiz ","
prompt: .asciiz "Enter numbers (amount must be to a power of 2) :"
.text   

.globl main

main:

#addi $s5, $zero, 0     #stores zero into $s5
la $a1,array



li $v0,4            #Prompt for user input
la $a0, prompt          #Displays message
syscall

li $v0, 5           # read integer 
syscall 
add $s0,$v0,$zero       #store input into $s0
sw $s0, array           #stores into memory

li $v0, 5           # read integer 
syscall 
add $s1,$v0,$zero
sw $s1, array +4

li $v0, 5           # read integer 
syscall 
add $s2,$v0,$zero
sw $s2, array +8

li $v0, 5           # read integer 
syscall 
add $s3,$v0,$zero
sw $s3, array +12

li $v0, 5           # read integer 
syscall 
add $s4,$v0,$zero
sw $s4, array +16
```

etc...

Comment: Why can't you, for example, populate 8 registers, write them to memory, then overwrite the registers, write them to memory, etc

Comment: Hmm, I could do that.

Comment: How about a loop that runs from 0-32 to avoid repeated code?